# How many dimensions are there in total?

Tags: string-theory, spacetime, spacetime-dimensions, compactification

I happened to get my hands on a string theory book where its been said that the universe's fundamental particle i.e. the string, takes about ten dimensions for specifying itself under symmetry. What are those?

Comment: I'm confused by the multiple downvotes on this. It seems like a legitimate question for this site. Would the voters care to clarify their positions?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://www.physics.stackexchange.com/q/29328/ .

Comment: @wsc: I downvoted because the question is too "popular science"-ish and doesn't really make it clear what it is asking "specifying itself under symmetry"?! Sounds like something taken from an innnaccurate popular science book like "String theory for dummies"

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what theory are you useing, in theory of relativity there are only four dimensions $x^{\mu}$ but in another theory like general relativity there is a higher dimension which there is a constraint to eliminate the artifical 5th dimension (schwartzchild metric).

Comment: Wrong. Schwarzschild is a solution to GR. KK theory is what you're talking about. And GR can be generalised.